# setxkbmap in xmonad problem

Tags: layout, xmonad

Why, when some setxkbmap command have been run, all default xmobar's keyboard bindings have been disabled and unusable?

```
setxkbmap -layout 'ru,us' -option 'grp:caps_toggle' &
```

What's wrong with that command and how can I set as default that layout change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `xmonad`'s keybindings are by keysym, not keycode, and there are no command bindings for Cyrillic keysyms.  ([Bug 398](http://code.google.com/p/xmonad/issues/detail?id=398))  You should probably copy the default key bindings (see http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/src/XMonad-Config.html) and add Cyrillic versions.